# I configured webpack for multiple pages with Bootstrap 4 and font-awesome and it's is super slow and makes my computer stuck

Tags: performance, webpack, workflow, boilerplate, starter-kits

I have created a webpack configuration that uses bootstrap 4 and fontawesome. It has multiple entrypoints and deals with multiple html pages at the same time.

For those who are curiousI have created a repository of my workflow too:

## [github](https://github.com/Juni4567/gulp-to-webpack)

It works fine and I am happy with the output. What bothers me is the speed of it. The workflow is super slow which I am unable to figure out. The CPU usage goes 100% as soon as I change some file.

> Here is my webpack configuration file:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: './src/js/home.js',
        login: './src/js/login.js',
        signup: './src/js/signup.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'home.html',
            template: 'src/home.html',
            chunks: ['home'],
            inject: false
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'login.html',
            template: 'src/login.html',
            chunks: ['login'],
            inject: false
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'signup.html',
            template: 'src/signup.html',
            chunks: ['signup'],
            inject: false
        }),

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|gif)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
                        name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
                        publicPath: '/'
                    }
                }]
            },

            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "postcss-loader",
                    "resolve-url-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },

        ]
    },
};
```